# Remote Desktop Connection from Different Keyboards

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop, keyboard-layout

I have a dedicated server I connect to via RDC from a US laptop, which works fine. I just got a French laptop with an AZERTY keyboard, and when I remote to that dedicated server, it's as if I'm on a US keyboard (e.g. when I press A it displays as Q). What do I do so I can remote to that dedicated server from either laptop, and type in that laptop's keyboard (e.g. pressing the A key on the French laptop displaying A on the server)?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The server's localization / kbd is set to US. So you need to change on the server either localization to FR, or at least the keyboard layout to AZERTY.

Comment: Worked great!  Thank you.